# Pyinstaller executable not running

Tags: pyinstaller

I made a small application using Python and Tkinter and I then tried to convert it into an executable file using Pyinstaller.
Pyinstaller creates the executable in the folder 'dist' as expected but when I double click on the file it will not run. Can you please help me find out what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me.. I use the process of elimination to discover the cause.
Simply remove modules from your code until the program execution actually begins.  You can detect if you code is running by putting a dbgview output statement at the top of your code.  Once your code execution works... you'll know what module or section of code is the root of the problem with regard to pyinstaller.